# A problem of alignment with "ulem"

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ulem

I defined a underline style by `ulem` package to add a `=` sign under each character, as follows:

```
\newcommand{\suline}{\bgroup\markoverwith{\raisebox{-0.6em}{=}}\ULon}
```

With `parskip` package added, the result looks fine:

[image]

However, when the underlined text is centered, or if `parskip` is not added, then the `=` signs are not properly aligned with the text:

[image]

How could I fix this problem?

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}

\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\suline}{\bgroup\markoverwith{\raisebox{-0.6em}{=}}\ULon}

\begin{document}

\suline{Some text}
\begin{center}
    \suline{Some text}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These underlines are made with leaders. And leaders are aligned to each other. So if you shift the text around their position relative to the text changes:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \usepackage{parskip}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\ttdefault}

\usepackage{ulem}

\newcommand{\suline}{\bgroup\markoverwith{\raisebox{-0.6em}{=}}\ULon}

\begin{document}
\suline{Some text}

\hspace*{3pt}\suline{Some text}

\hspace*{4.5pt}\suline{Some text}

\hspace*{6pt}\suline{Some text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need a line break, you can put them in boxes:

```
\mbox{\suline{Some text}}

\hspace*{3pt}\mbox{\suline{Some text}}

\hspace*{4.5pt}\mbox{\suline{Some text}}

\hspace*{6pt}\mbox{\suline{Some text}}
```

Then you get this:

[image]